# Vertex and graphs . prove trees.

Tags: trees

Can anyone tell me how to prove that every tree with at least 1 edge has at least 2 leaves? Im currently studyinng proof of trees.

Comment: Suppose the graph is finite. Then consider the longest path in the graph between any two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The two (distinct!) endpoints of a maximal path are leaves.

Comment: is there a way to answer this in a professional way?